# How can I make easy job to casting enum member to int?

Tags: c++, c++11, enums

How can I make easy job to casting enum member to int? I know an `enum class` can't have member functions. But is there no any way to do something like `myEnum::foo.toInt()` I'm looking for an alternative to `static_cast<int>(myEnum::foo)` because do this every time I need to put this into a `int` variable is a lot of typeing and I don't want to use old `enum` (non-`enum class`) because I want to have type safely and each enum with your own scope.

Comment: If you are casting that often you're doing something wrong.

Comment: "Easy casting" *and* "type safety" sounds a bit contradictory.

Comment: It is easy already.  Not sure why you need a static_cast to assign an enum member to an int since enum members are already integral types.  ( enum eColors { eRed, eGreen, eBlue };  int red = eRed;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using a utility function that casts any enum value to its underlying type:

```
template<typename Enum>
typename std::underlying_type<Enum>::type to_underlying(Enum e) {
    return static_cast<typename std::underlying_type<Enum>::type>(e);
}
```

You can then write:

```
to_underlying(Enum::foo);
```

Comment: I'd call it `to_integral` myself (as it converts it to the underlying integral type, and integral is shorter than underlying).

Comment: If it's declared as `enum class : char` this function will return `char` type too?

Comment: @ecatmur: My compiler seems doesn't support it: no type named 'underlying_type' in namespace 'std' what am I missing? (I'm using clang 3.3)

Comment: @Jack `underlying_type` is in `<type_traits>`.

Comment: I included this and `<iostream>`

Comment: The code from this page (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/underlying_type) doesn't compile I think it's clang doesn't support it :(

Comment: @Jack try updating your compiler.